# Cannot find SFML Template in XCode 8

Tags: xcode, sfml

I've been trying to set up `SFML` on Xcode 8 for a C++ Project, but I am having trouble finding the correct template. I am using this [tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-osx.php) from the official SFML website.

I've followed all the instructions before the **Create your first SFML program** division. Despite adding templates to my `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates` folder, I still cannot find the SFML template in XCode as shown in the screenshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctvJH.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the directory where you added the project templates. You need to add the templates to the following directory:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/GroupName
```

GroupName is the group name in the New Project Assistant. In the screenshot you linked to, the group names are Application, Framework & Library, and Other. You may want to create your own group name, such as SFML.

You may need to manually add the Project Templates and GroupName folders.